# Why is this not returning 3 as a prime?

Tags: python

```
def isItPrime(n):
    p='true'
    if not n==2:
        for x in range(2,round(math.sqrt(n))+1):#I'm taking the square root to make the program more efficient, and adding the one so it doesn't create ranges like: range(2,2)
            if n%x==0:
                p='false'
                break
    return p

def findPrimes(n):
    primes=[]
    x=2 #if I change this value to 3 it does find 3 as a prime
    while len(primes)<n:
        if isItPrime(x)=='true':
            primes.append(x)
            x+=1
        x+=1
    return primes

print(isItPrime(3)) #true
print(findPrimes(10)) #[2, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31]
```

returns:
**true,**
**[2, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31]**
I don't know what else to add here but it's not letting me post until I add some more details

Comment: Python has `True` and `False` types.  No need to use strings.  Then you can also just say `if isItPrime(x):`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
>     if isItPrime(x)=='true':
>         primes.append(x)
>         x+=1
>     x+=1
> ```

2 is a prime so it appends 2 to `primes`, then changes `x` to 3 then finishes the `if` then changes `x` to 4. Then starts the loop again.

Thus `3` is skipped.

Don't increment `x` inside the `if`.